# Jquery multipage html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I came across the problem of trying to link several multipage html files with jquery mobile and found out the hard way that when using ajax, jquery mobile will not show the full document, rather the first page.

I looked up the problem and found todd thomsons subpage widget but was unable to get the plugin to work. So now I'm trying to find out, with out using ajax, is it possible to load an external multipage html file, but not leave the ios web app window and launch safari?

I saw this bit of javascript in my searches but I'm not sure how it would work out.

```
<a href="file2.html" data-icon="back" data-ajax="false" class="file2">Log Out</a></li>

$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
  $('.file2').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.assign("file.html");
  });
});
```

So i guess my question is, with javascript, is it possible to load an external html file with out leaving the web app view?

Comment: Your external file is it a jQM multipage file or just some other html file?

Comment: its a jqm multipage file as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly (you need to change page to `file.html` which is a multipage jQM document) you can try

```
<li><a href="file1.html" rel="external" data-icon="back">Log Out</a></li>
```

or if you need to change page programmatically

```
<li><a id="logout" href="#" data-icon="back">Log Out</a></li>
```

and

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', '#logout', function() {
  $('#logout').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.changePage("file1.html");
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that got it to work. Some CSS proporties didn't load over but I think I can work that out my self.

Comment: Now I know this works for that particular instance when I define which a tag this applies to, but what about making this a universal function. So that I give each a tag an element id of the html file so that way the JavaScript will take that id and add a .html to the end of it so I would only have to write it once? Would I change "#file" to 'elementID' ?